# Na+ and K+ ions and EMF

Tags: biology

I understand that electrons moving in a conductor will generate photons by colliding with the conductor lattice and that this generates photons.  What about Na+ or K+ ions in a salt solution, particularly when they are moving thru ion channels?  What kind of particle (photon, boson?) is generated by this to create an EM wave and by what process?

Comment: Electrons moving in a conductor generate sound quanta called phonons, not photons.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797620/2451

Comment: Hi kevinohlemiller. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: OK, so far I've had 6 people explain why they won't or can't answer my question.  You all look a bit silly, it seems to me.  Bye Bye.